# Default job time limit in Slurm

Tags: slurm

I want to allow the user scheduling a job to list any job time limit using `-t, --time=<time>`. However, when the user does not set a time limit I'd like to impose a default time limit, for example 1 hour. I can't find any setting in slurm.conf to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default time limit is set per partition. If not specified, the maximum time limit is used:

> DefaultTime
>
> Run time limit used for jobs that don't specify a value. If not set then MaxTime will be used. Format is the same as for MaxTime.

Example:

```
PartitionName=debug Nodes=dev[0-8,18-25] MaxTime=12:00:00 DefaultTime=00:30:00 Default=YES
```

This will set the maximum wall time for the partition to 12 hours and the default, if not specified by the user, to 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set default time limit twice, right? If user do not specify time then the job will be terminated automatically when the job is completed. You can read about [**-t, --time here**](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html). Anyways, the default time limit is the partition's default time limit. So, you can have it changed as you like.

Here's an example of `slurm.conf` to set time-limit for partition -

```sh
# slurm.conf file

# for CPU
PartitionName=cpu Nodes=ALL Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP

# for GPU
PartitionName=gpu Nodes=ALL MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```